Firebase app check and turnstile provider
Recently I installed Turnstile firebase extension for my web app to replace the re-captcha enterprise.
I started receiving complaints from users who were unable to use my app. Around 1.5% encountered errors due to the app check verification.
Is there any way to display challenges for people, so they can prove they are humans and not bots?  I tired to do to change Turnstile settings to managed, but seems like it didn't work, because it runs as app check provider at Firebase.
Will appreciate any advice or help
